# Android pre-release app with beta with issues?

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I have my android game on pre-release. After publishing my beta apk and making it available for all countries, it still shows up after one day as unavailable.
Even if I create an internal track and share the link with the users, they can only see the pre-register option.
Am I missing something or pre-release cannot be used with betas?

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.monkeyibrow.worldsoccerchamps
keeps showing: "App not available. A testing version of this app hasn't been published yet or isn't available for this account."

Answer (score 0):

it turns out google is taking 7 days to review the published games. had to wait several days for my beta version to come out.